# How do I merge a local Postgres dump to AWS RDS without the -c flag?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have version A of my PostgreSQL database in AWS RDS and version B on my local machine. DB B was created from a dump of DB A and has been updated locally. I am trying to merge the data I have locally to RDS.

A has data that B doesn't have and B has data that A doesn't have, hence I cannot use the `-c` flag in `pg_dump` (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810078/merging-local-postgresql-database-file-to-aws-rds-database)).

I export my database with `pg_dump`:

```
pg_dump -f dump.sql mydb
```

I try to import my database to RDS using `psql`:

```
psql -h ABC.XYZ.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U myself mydb < dump.sql
```

This updates schema, i.e. adds columns I had locally to RDS, but fails to insert any values into these columns. I get the following error for every table that exists in DB A:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_pkey"
```

As I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448340/postgresql-duplicate-key-violates-unique-constraint), my sequence may be out of sync, but this seems odd given I get it for every table in DB A, and DB B was created from a dump of DB A.

If I use the `-c` flag with `pg_dump` the merge works but all of the data in DB A that DB B did not have gets deleted.

How do I merge my local database into the remote one on AWS without losing data?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to modify any of the existing rows, you can use `pg_dump`'s option `--on-conflict-do-nothing`, new in v12.

This will *not* add any new columns. `pg_dump` is not a schema migration tool.